# React - Create new array of objects dismissing object copies using key value pairs

Tags: reactjs

I have two arrays ,and want to filter out matches and create a new array only containing objects that did not match in either array,

```
const firstObjectArray = [
  { name: 'six', show: 'six  times' },
  { name: 'Jonas', show: 'Dark' },
  { name: 'Mulder', show: 'The X Files' },
  { name: 'Ragnar', show: 'Vikings' },
  { name: 'Scully', show: 'The X Files' },
];

const secondObjectArray = [
  { name: 'Eleven', show: 'Stranger Things' },
  { name: 'Jonas', show: 'Dark' },
  { name: 'Mulder', show: 'The X Files' },
  { name: 'Ragnar', show: 'Vikings' },
  { name: 'Scully', show: 'The X Files' },
];
```

something like

`var remainingArr = firstObjectArray.filter(data => data.name !== secondObjectArray.contains.name);`

so that i am only left with

remainingArr = [{ name: 'six', show: 'six  times' }]

as it was the only one that did not match

Answer (score 2):

```js
const firstObjectArray = [
  { name: 'six', show: 'six  times' },
  { name: 'Jonas', show: 'Dark' },
  { name: 'Mulder', show: 'The X Files' },
  { name: 'Ragnar', show: 'Vikings' },
  { name: 'Scully', show: 'The X Files' },
];

const secondObjectArray = [
  { name: 'Eleven', show: 'Stranger Things' },
  { name: 'Jonas', show: 'Dark' },
  { name: 'Mulder', show: 'The X Files' },
  { name: 'Ragnar', show: 'Vikings' },
  { name: 'Scully', show: 'The X Files' },
];

const result = firstObjectArray.filter(item => {
  return !secondObjectArray.some(i => i.name === item.name && item.show === i.show)
})

console.log(result)
```